# I am using angularjs and want to show popup window using bootstrap and spring servlet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs to show many pages one of these pages contains smart-table I used it to show the "users" details
when I want to edit one of the users I want to show the edit page as popup window

my app.js

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'home',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'login',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .when('/register', {
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        templateUrl: 'register',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

     .when('/users', {
        controller: 'usersListController',
        templateUrl: 'users',
    })

    .when('/user-modal', {
        templateUrl: 'user_model',
    })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}
```

my cotroller to show the popup window

```
this.openUser = function(row) {
                    service.GetUsers(row.userId).then(function(data){

                        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({

                            templateUrl : '/user_model',
                            controller : 'MonitoringModalController',

                    };
```

and I used spring servlet for redirection and this is the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_model", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView user_model(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try{
            logger.info("MappingController --> Users List...");
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.fatal(new MasterProtectionLogger().reportError("MappingController.users()", e, logger));
        }
        return new ModelAndView("users/user_model");
    }
```

but one I click on the button to show the popup window I get this error

angular.js:10765 GET http://localhost:8080/MasterProtection/user_model 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765sendReq @ angular.js:10558serverRequest @ angular.js:10268processQueue @ angular.js:14792(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14808$eval @ angular.js:16052$digest @ angular.js:15870$apply @ angular.js:16160(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23618dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
angular.js:12520 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ./user_model (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `user-modal` and `user-model`. Looks like you misprinted.

Here:

```
 templateUrl : './user-modal',
```

and here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_model", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: sorry but I changed the names while I am trying to find soluation for my problem,

Comment: as it still returns 404 error, your angular calls the link, that not exist. Try to ensure http://localhost:8080/MasterProtection/user_model GET request rich your controller. I would try this without Angular, but just from browser.

Comment: yes the request rich the controller and I get the page on the browser